# measures on groups without assuming a locally compact group topology

Tags: gr.group-theory, measure-theory

I'm interested in knowing whether there exists any kind of theory for measures on groups without assuming that it's the Haar measure for a locally compact group topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translastion-invariant, locally finite measure on a topological group.

As I recall, there is something like this in Hewitt & Ross Vol. I

> *Hewitt, E.; Ross, K. A.*, Abstract harmonic analysis. Vol. I: Structure of topological groups. Integration theory. Group representations, Die Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften. 115. Berlin-Göttingen-Heidelberg: Springer-Verlag. VIII, 519 p. (1963). [ZBL0115.10603](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0115.10603).

What the exact conditions were, I do not remember.  But the conclusion was that the measure is essentially Haar measure on a locally compact group which is in sense a "completion" of the given group.

Comment: What is the question you're answering? The question as asked now is extremely broad (and vague), and hence since your answer is accepted, it might have an interpretation I didn't guess.